# IIS 7.5 404 Error for .PDF files

Tags: c#, iis, redirect, iis-7.5, sitecore

I am running into an issue where I am re-directing a .pdf extension url using IIS 7.5. Here is what is weird happening: When my URL does not contains `.pdf` in it like: `http://mySite/documents/forms/test` the pdf (test.pdf) opens up perfectly. However, when I am opening through like this: `http://mySite/documents/forms/test.pdf` it is showing me

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I browse through couple of links like: http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/case-of-the-disappearing-pdf/

and

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979543

But dont know whether they are appropriate. Also tried debugging through fiddler as this link mentioned: http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/case-of-the-disappearing-pdf/

When I am saving the **Response Body** the pdf file does not get saved in correct format. So I am guessing there is some kind of file corruption? Maybe? But my file opens up perfectly when I do not include the .pdf in the URL. Dont know what is going on :\

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the `application/pdf` mime type is configured properly and that there is no ISAPI filter configured for the .pdf extension?

Comment: In my MIME type there is .pdf and its Entry Type is Local. I tried to change it to octet-stream but no luck. Then I changed it back to pdf. There is no filter for .pdf under ISAPI.

Comment: In addtion to Fiddler, check the IIS logs to see what request IIS is receiving? It sounds to me like some kind of URL rewriting is going on  (ie. providing "friendly URL" type paths to a given resource or location). I'm not familiar with SiteCore, but if your IIS has the URL Rewrite module set, maybe check the rewrite rules like shown [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I have to change the web.config file to allow .pdf file to open in the browser:

```
 <preprocessRequest help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.PreprocessRequestProcessor">
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.SuppressFormValidation, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.NormalizeRawUrl, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.IIS404Handler, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx, pdf</param>
      <param desc="Blocked extensions (comma separated)">*</param>
      <param desc="Blocked extensions that stream files (comma separated)">*</param>
      <param desc="Blocked extensions that do not stream files (comma separated)" />
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.StripLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  </preprocessRequest>
```

Comment: I know this is a long shot because this is an old post, but where did you place this within the web.config file?