# File won't display on publish asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a pdf that I want to display to a user.  When I run the code from the IDE, it displays no problem, however when I publish the application to the server, it generates a 404.

I have placed the file Instructions.pdf in a folder I created called /Files

Here is my view link:

```
<h2>Placeholder</h2>
    <p>
        Click below for instructions on how to use the tool.
    </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/InstructionsPDF">Instructions &raquo;</a></p>
```

Here is the controller action:

```
public ActionResult InstructionsPDF()
    {
        return File(HostingEnvironment.MapPat("~/Files/Instructions.pdf"), "application/pdf"
    }
```

Having looked this question up, a common solution was to change the build action to "Content".  I have checked the properties on the pdf and they are as follows:

```
Browse to URL            |
Build Action             | Content
Copy to Output Directory | Copy always
Custom Tool              |
Custom Tool Namespace    |
```

Any suggestions are more thank welcome, thank you for your time.

Comment: You could try using HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the file is in fact present in the Files directory on the server.  If it's there, but still generating a 404, your web server might not be configured to serve pdf files (application/pdf mime type).

See here for example: [IIS 7.5 404 Error for .PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409424/iis-7-5-404-error-for-pdf-files)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have looked and it is appearing in the file system, I will try your link.

Comment: I am not sure where to place the specified answer in the web.config, do you know where it should be placed?

Comment: This specific answer is for the SiteCore CMS system so it does not apply to your scenario.  Check the other comments in the thread.  Some of them may apply.

Comment: Searching further has brought me to this Microsoft article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/979543 I might try out the specified fix then post the answer if it works.